# What information is my developer story missing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

My profile shows a warning icon next to the Developer Story Beta. When hovering over it, the following text is displayed:

[image]

However, clicking through to the developer story shows no indication about what information is missing exactly.

Comment: This has become a problem on the careers-site as well. Now it just says "Completion score" and gives a seemingly arbitrary percentage where it before used to give a breakdown of missing or low quality points on your CV.

Comment: @J.Steen The careers site shows my score at 100%, but still suggests I should improve my profile by adding three projects - despite I have eight projects listed there.

Comment: Consistent, for sure! =D

Comment: I had the same indicator on my profile. I went in, made a change (didn't add or remove anything0 and now it's gone. very confusing!

Comment: @DavidG interesting, thanks for the tip! I'll leave it untouched, though, until someone from the SO staff swings by, as the current state may be useful for their debugging purposes.

Comment: @Mureinik There's definitely a bug there (it keeps saying we need more information even though we have them all), we're on it!

Comment: @Stéphane hmm, the warning seems to be gone now. Not sure if you did anything there or if it's just a refresh/caching issue, but seems fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue should be fixed, we recently pushed a fix to production.